# How to get full day & month names from UTC date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert a date that's stored as a string in a JSON file into UTC string format using JavaScript.

Here is my JSON:

```
{
    "createdDate": {
        "utc": "2022-08-20T12:18:48.6588096Z",
        "local": "2022-08-20T12:18:48.6588096"
    }
}
```

Here is the function I am trying to use, but I'm not sure why it's displaying GMT:

```
let createdByUtc = new Date(resp.createdDate.utc).toUTCString()
```

**Actual Result:**

Sat, 20 Aug 2022 12:08:52 GMT

**Required Result:**

Saturday, August 20, 2022 at 12:08 PM UTC

Can someone please show me how I can get my `createdByUtc` variable in the required format?

Comment: Check out the [Internationalization `DateTimeFormat` facility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with defining some options like below .

```
let createdByUtc = JSON.parse( '{"utc": "2022-08-20T12:18:48.6588096Z", "local": "2022-08-20T12:18:48.6588096"}');
var newDate =new Date(createdByUtc.utc)

const options = {
  weekday: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric',
  hour:'numeric',
  minute:'numeric'
};
options.timeZone = 'UTC';
options.timeZoneName = 'short';
console.log(newDate.toLocaleString('en-US', options))

//Saturday, August 20, 2022, 12:18 PM UTC
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) instance with a configuration for a UTC representation with appropriate date and time styles:

```js
const {format} = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', 
    { timeZone: 'UTC', dateStyle: 'full', timeStyle: 'long' }
);
    
// Example
let dt = new Date("2022-08-20T12:18:48.6588096Z");
console.log(format(dt));
```